# Fail on codeigniter upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using upload class on codeigniter but it throws me an error saying file path is invalid.

I printed the `$this->upload->data`and it doesn't show file data, but the upload folder I setted exists and is shown on it.

```
array(14) {
    ["file_name"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["file_type"]=> string(0) ""
    ["file_path"]=> string(36) "homologacao/assets/images/promocoes/" 
    ["full_path"]=> string(36) "homologacao/assets/images/promocoes/"  
    ["raw_name"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["orig_name"]=> string(0) ""  
    ["client_name"]=> string(0) ""  
    ["file_ext"]=> string(0) ""  
    ["file_size"]=> string(0) ""  
    ["is_image"]=> bool(false)  
    ["image_width"]=> string(0) ""  
    ["image_height"]=> string(0) ""  
    ["image_type"]=> string(0) ""  
    ["image_size_str"]=> string(0) ""  
}
```

But when I get the `$_FILES`data, it shows the uploaded file data

```
array(1) {
    ["imagem"]=> array(5) { 
        ["name"]=> string(68) "3bf514d6cbb31410ee47e8cbcc79c81588a6740fb4264209a1531077e0fcc0a9.jpg" 
        ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpomUcFo" 
        ["error"]=> int(0) 
        ["size"]=> int(3571) 
    } 
}
```

I double checked my code and I think I'm setting things the right way

```
/*code slice with the upload part */

$config['upload_path'] = 'homologacao/assets/images/promocoes/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'png|jpg|gif';
$config['max_size'] = '1024';
$config['encrypt_name'] = true;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$field_name = 'imagem';
if ($this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
    /* do stuff */
} else {
    var_dump($this->upload->data());
    var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
    var_dump($_FILES);

    die();
}
```

Why is file upload not working and how can I solve it?

Comment: What r u getting in display_errors()

Comment: Something like "invalid upload file path"

Answer (score 0):

Your file path should be like this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './homologacao/assets/images/promocoes/';
```

Comment: Is your "homologacao/*" folder in the web root?

Comment: Yes, it is.

also, I tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/homologacao/assets/images/promocoes/'` with no luck.

Comment: Did you try to set permissions 777?

Comment: Try with `$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'homologacao/assets/images/promocoes/';`

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

Just setted `DOCUMENT_ROOT` on the upload path

```
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'homologacao/assets/images/promocoes/';
```

Thank you everybody who helped me trying to figure it out.